# How to find a parent.sibling select with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a list with products and every product has a select where you can select the number of items you want, and I need to find the select value when I click on id="laggtillikundvagn".

If I only have one select on the page, then this is working `$(document).find('#shopform select[id=antal]').val()`

So I have tried variants of this.

```js
console.log(
  $(this).parents().siblings().find('#shopform select[id=antal]').val()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-content-inner">

  <select id="antal" class="antal SumoUnder" name="antal">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>

  </select>

</div>

<div class="card-footer notranslate">

  <div>
    <a href="#" id="laggtillikundvagn" class="kundvagnknapp" data-produktid="790">ADD IT</a>
  </div>


</div>
The next product, with a new select comes here....
```

So how can I get the value from the select?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to create a [mcve]

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs?

Comment: The select you're attempting to get the value of has an `id`, therefore that must be unique and the DOM traversal logic is redundant. Just use `$('#antal').val()`

Comment: @freedomn-m there will be more than one ".antal" in the form. See my answer

Comment: @freedomn-m in my answer it does not matter

Comment: `.parents()` returns all of the parents - you probably only want a specific one, so use `.closest()`, but from the limited HTML provided, it's impossible for us to help other than a guess.  At a guess: `$(".kundvagnknapp").click(function() { console.log($(this).closest(".card-content-wrapper").find(".antal").val()); });`

Comment: @mplungjan was too late to edit - so readded comment without `form` - most ppl would only use one form.   As an aside, using .prev() makes it very brittle and will stop working if OP adds a div between footer and inner, but you can only go with what's provided.

Comment: @freedomn-m see my second example

Comment: You should fix your markup to not have repeating ids.  That is invalid by web standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not use ID since it is obviously duplicate
2. Use relative to the sibling of what you want:
3. BETTER idea would be to use the data-produktid as in the second example:

```js
$(".kundvagnknapp").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop link

  console.log(
    $(this).closest(".card-footer") // parent's parent
      .prev()          // sibling div
      .find('.antal')  // select
      .val()
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-content-inner">

  <select class="antal SumoUnder" name="antal">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>

  </select>

</div>

<div class="card-footer notranslate">

  <div>
    <a href="#" class="kundvagnknapp" data-produktid="790">ADD IT</a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Solving it completely:

```js
$(".kundvagnknapp").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop link

  console.log(
    $("#div_"+$(this).attr("data-produktid")+" .antal").val()
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-content-inner" id="div_790">

  <select class="antal SumoUnder" name="antal">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>

  </select>

</div>

<div class="card-footer notranslate">

  <div>
    <a href="#" class="kundvagnknapp" data-produktid="790">ADD IT</a>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mplungjan, second example works great!!